# Tikz and standalone, include single picture/page doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I've created a standalone file containing two `tikzpicture` environments. If I compile the file by itself, I am seeing two pages generated. So far so good.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{...}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{...}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to include only the first or the second one of them in my main document:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includestandalone[page=2]{figures/diagrams}
  \caption{The enhanced diagram}
\end{figure}
```

Other than expected and documented, the result is both diagrams being printed side-by-side with the second one surpassing the right margin of the page.
Any idea what could be the issue?

[image: result]

**Edit, Solution:** Turns out the problem originated out of multiple errors. Maybe this will be a help for others:

1. @torbjørn-t brought to my attention, that the default `mode=tex` setting doesn't support the pages option. Be sure to activate one of the other inclusion modes in the main document. I decided to go with:

   ```
   \usepackage[mode=build]{standalone}
   ```
2. Next issue was, that the cascaded build now yielded the following error: `Package standalone Warning: Graphic '...' could not be build. Shell escape activated?`
   Be sure to enable shell escape.
3. In my case the above wasn't actually related to shell escape but to a build error inside the standalone `diagrams` document in combination with the fact, that it is located in the subdirectory `figures`. Turns out the build is executed in a different path and a `\include{general_properties}` couldn't be resolved correctly. To solve this and similar issues, be sure to check the individual log files next to your standalone file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't used this myself, but the behaviour depends on the `mode` setting, see the description of `\includestandalone` in the `standalone` manual (section 5.3). For example, with

```
\includestandalone[mode=image,page=2]{filename}
```

it will include (page 2 of) `filename.pdf`. With

```
\includestandalone[mode=build,page=2]{filename}
```

it will compile `filename.tex` and include `filename.pdf`. There is also `mode=buildnew` which will compile the other file only if it is newer than the PDF, or `mode=buildmissing` which compiles it only if the PDF isn't there. The default is likely `mode=tex`, which is similar to `\input`, so it adds the code directly (sans preamble and `document` environment).

You can also set the mode as an option to the package, e.g.

```
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
```

or use `\standaloneconfig`, e.g.

```
\standaloneconfig{mode=buildmissing}
```

if you want the same setting for all `\includestandalone`s.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick answer. I knew about those options and immediately played around with them. Sadly none corrects the described behavior.

Comment: @Mazzen Then I'm at a loss, because they worked perfectly fine here. Without `mode=image` (or one of the `build`s -- note they require compiling with `--shell-escape`), I got both pages, but with `mode=image` I only got the second page. Instead of your second code snippet, could you show a complete, minimal document (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) demonstrating the problem? That might make it possible to work out what's wrong.

Comment: We are getting closer. I've switched over to the `build` option. My diagrams are included as before but I'm seeing the error message `Package standalone Warning: Graphic '...' could not be build. Shell escape activated?`. Shell escape is enabled and I was able to test it's function with `pdftexcmds`. I'll look deeper, seems like my document/the MWE is not the problem.

Comment: Got it working. The error was something completely different and a wild mixture of imperfect details :) I'll add the solution to my OP. Thanks for your input, without it I would probably not have troubleshooted for that long.